# CMS : Wordpress or Mezzanine ? (or other)

Tags: wordpress, oracle, content-management-system, admin, mezzanine

My mission is to use a CMS to make a site with an easy administration page, the main goal would therefore be to customize the default administration page of a CMS. I am hesitating between 2 CMS (but willing to take any other suggestion ^^) : wordpress and mezzanine. The CMS would have to work with Oracle data base.

Wordpress :

- I don't know php but someone told me that it is not that difficult to learn
- I have seen the admin page on another computer than mine, but when trying to install wamp (before downloading the wordpress files) on my Windows computer, I have encountered some issues that I have not yet managed to resolve so I am afraid it would be a little complicated.

Mezzanine :

- I know it would work with oracle (although I don't know how yet ^^)
- In the past 3 weeks, I have learned the bases of python and django, and I have managed to create some simple django apps
- I have installed it without too much trouble on a Lubuntu virtual machine (but although I have installed the latest mezzanine version, it works with an old version of django : 1.6)
- All the topics I found about mezzanine go back to more than a year ago, so I fear mezzanine to be a little "over"

Other things to know about me:

- About the languages : I currently only know C and a little Python but I don't mind learning other languages for this project.
- I don't know much about databases